# Not able to create patch with Eclipse using perforce

Tags: eclipse, perforce

I have been trying to create a team patch using Eclipse(Juno) using the perforce plugin and it keeps on showing me the following error

[image: Patch Fail Message]

I can do all other operations easily without any credential issues, so I am not sure why I am getting this message only for this operation. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Had the same problem after I upgrade the plug in to latest 2013 Service Patch 2

Answer (score 0):

I found that even I get this error and warning. The patch is still successfully created. I have tried creating patch in clipboard. It works. While creating patch to file system, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Hope this helps.